# Firebase storage, cannot get download url successfully. (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, imageview, google-cloud-firestore

this is my code so far.

```
 public void getimage() {
    FirebaseStorage storagi = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference imagerefi = storagi.getReference();
        userimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewuser);
        StorageReference pathReference = imagerefi.child("images/"+somename);

        imagerefi.child("images/"+somename).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
                uri2 = uri.toString();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors
            }
        });



Glide.with(this).asDrawable().apply(fitCenterTransform()).load(uri2).into(userimage);


    }
```

I have tried without the success listener, and many other things. When i simply copy-paste the url from the firebase console, i get the image working perfectly. but the uri2 doesnt work as intended.

I basically want to get the file that is named after a firebase user uid and inside a folder called images inside the root directory of firebase storage, and display it on an imageview.

Thanks a lot for any help! I have been trying for weeks to solve this issue.

//some of the code has been recently modified from a stactoverflow post //therefore does nothing in this current configuration, i am aware of that

Comment: post snippet of your firebase storage hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, just move the following line of code:

```
Glide.with(this).asDrawable().apply(fitCenterTransform()).load(uri2).into(userimage);
```

Inside the callback right after the following line of code:

```
uri2 = uri.toString();
```

Remember, `onSuccess()` method has an asynchronous behaviour and if you try to use the value of the `uri2` variable outside this method, it will always be `null` because by the time you are trying to access it, its value is not available yet. If you want to use it outside that method, I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. It worked. I had to also change the with(this) inside glide, to myactivity.this. But now everything works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I wish somename is a valid name. try this

just move the line of set the image in imageview inside onSuccess to make sure the uri2 is the url from the firebaseStorage

```
public void getimage() {
    FirebaseStorage storagi = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference imagerefi = storagi.getReference();
        userimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewuser);
        StorageReference pathReference = imagerefi.child("images/"+somename);

        imagerefi.child("images/"+somename).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
                uri2 = uri.toString();
           Glide.with(this).asDrawable().apply(fitCenterTransform()).load(uri2).into(userimage);
 }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors

                Log.e("ERRORLOADING",exception.getMessage());
            }
        });





    }
```